# Best way of identifying and comparing files in a client-server architecture

Tags: hash, comparison, checksum, crc

I have a `DataStore` made for the purpose of storing datasets. The users can upload datasets to the datastore, but first they check if the dataset exists in the `DataStore`, and it only gets uploaded if the returned value is `false`. See sequence diagram:

[image: UML 2.2 Sequence diagram]

This is implemented by identifying datasets with their checksums and comparing the clients checksum with the ones in the `DataStore`. The algorithm for now is CRC32. After some research it came clear that this can be unsafe, due to the Birthday-problem: [With CRC32, for 1% probability of collision, there needs to be 9300 datasets, and 5000 datasets for 25% probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table).

The numbers tell this is very much risky with CRC32. The checksum needs to be easily calculated, so it does not put too much load on the client. Is there a way – a tricky secondary check maybe – to tell that the datasets with the matching checksums differ? Or the only way is to pick a function with more bits by considering the maximum amount of datasets?

*PS: I know; all kinds of questions about file comparison have been asked already, but I couldn't find any that answers all of my questions.*

Comment: use a good hash like sha1 and the size of the file in bytes. For example: `328be60d5b2644fbb778b70d34e201ba08d02dba:27247300` (which is the newest `OSXHIGuidelines.pdf`).

Comment: @DanD. Nice suggestion, you should've posted this as answer. Does the filesize change the probabilities? A mathematical demonstration and/or a more detailed explanation would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It can't avoid the collision so use hash with more bits to minimize a probability of the collision.